# How to create a similar table on remote machine

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table on my local machine which has the same description as some other table on a remote machine. I just want to create the table with same columns, don't worry about the row data.

The table has around 150 columns, so its very tedious to write the `CREATE TABLE` command. Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Not so elegant,connect to the remote,get the table definition copy it and paste it in local client

Comment: @Mihai I have copied the description into a csv file. How do I create a table out of this?

Comment: Why not use `mysqldump -d -other options  > tablestructure.sql` which dump only table structure.

Comment: Why do you use a csv file?Just copy it to a normal text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to something like:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;
```

which shows an sql query on how to create the certain table.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the description of your table on host1 with [DESCRIBE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html) by calling something like

```
DESCRIBE "myTable";
```

This will need some manual efforts to build up the `CREATE TABLE`-command, but has the advantage to get all important things on one view.

Anothe way would be to unload the structur of you database of host 1 you can use [mysql_dump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html). To do so call mysql_dump similar to

```
mysql_dump -d [options_like_user_and_host] databasename tabelname;
```

You will get a file which nearly directly can be used for your host 2. Atttention: Some relations e.g. to other tables might not be included.

Comment: Yes. But how do I create a table out of the description?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysqldump` to export database table structure only. Use `-d` or `--no-data` to achieve it. [Official document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data). For example

```
mysqldump -d -h hostname -u yourmysqlusername -p databasename > tablestruc.sql
```

If your local machine is accessible from remote, then change the hostname and execute this command from remote machine.